# Notepad++ how to find lines with a single word?

Tags: regex, notepad++, word-boundary

In the following:

```
1 et tegat vestes
2 Ipsam corpori 
3 adaptat 
4 thurificat illius postremams 
5 ante infimum gradu 
6 posito 
7 in modum crucis sibi
8 fimbrias diligenter aptatut 
9 lateribus
```

How would one make a regular expression to find lines with single words as in 3, 6 and 9? And optionally insert a line break at the beginning of each?

Comment: Define *optionally*.

Comment: Also, are the line numbers part of the text?

Answer (score 2):

Search:

```
^(\S+)$
```

Replace with:

```
\n\1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^\h*\w+\h*$
```

- `^` - Start of line
- `\h*` - optional leading horizontal whitespace
- `\w+` - 1 or more word symbols

You can use `\S` instead of `\w` to match any non-whitespace symbols.

To insert a linebreak, just replace with `\r\n$0`. You do not need any capturing groups since you can always reference the whole match with `$0` (or `$&`).

[image]